# ASP wildcard substring replace/remove

Tags: string, asp-classic, replace, str-replace

Morning,

I have a ASP variable which contains a load of HTML and other items.

```
dim mvariable : mvariable = "<div id=""constantID"">Some random text</div>"
```

My issue is that I need to replace the text within the `<div>` (using ASP, not clientside). The content of the `<div>` could be anything, but its ID attr is always the same.

How can I do this?

Jez D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable does not contains nested html elements you can do it using Regex. Otherwise, you have to use an html parser because Regex is not a parser and should not be used for such purposes.

```vb
dim mvariable : mvariable = "<div id=""constantID"">Some random text</div>"

Dim ReDiv
Set ReDiv = New RegExp
    ReDiv.IgnoreCase = True
    ReDiv.Pattern = "(<div id=""constantID"">)[\s\S]*?(</div>)"

Response.Write ReDiv.Replace(mvariable, "$1newContent$2")
```